# How to create a column that returns the size of another column in the entity?

Tags: nestjs

I'm trying to create a column that returns the length of another column in the same entity, what I've tried:

My Code

```
import { Entity, Column, OneToMany } from 'typeorm';
import { BaseEntity } from 'src/modules/shared/entities/base.entity';
import { Candidate } from './candidate.entity';
import { SarfStatusEnum } from '../enums/sarf-status.enum';
import { Expose } from 'class-transformer';


@Entity('Sarfs')
export class Sarf extends BaseEntity {

    @Column()
    site: string;

    @Column({ default: SarfStatusEnum.Started })
    status: number;

    @OneToMany(() => Candidate, candidate => candidate.sarf)
    candidates: Candidate[];

    @Expose()
    get candidateQtd() {
        return this.candidates.length;
    }

}
```

I need a column with this return:

```
    @Expose()
    get candidateQtd() {
        return this.candidates.length;
    }
```

This error happens:

`ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read property 'length' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't initialize the relationship on the service

Before

```
    async findAll(): Promise<Sarf[]> {
        return await this.sarfRepository.find();
    }
```

After

```
    async findAll(): Promise<Sarf[]> {
        return await this.sarfRepository.find({
            relations: ['candidates', 'candidates.forms', 'candidates.sarf']
        });
    }
```